# Understanding SemaphoreSlim problems?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, semaphore

I have a simple test code here with SemaphoreSlim

```
        static SemaphoreSlim mSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3);

        static async Task Main()
        {
            var tasks = new Task[5];

            for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                var taskNo = i;
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => DoWork($"task{taskNo}"));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        static async Task DoWork(string taskName)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                mSemaphore.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine($"{taskName}: doing {i}.");   
                await Task.Delay(1000); 

                mSemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
```

if i am correct: in my context my Semaphore should allow only 3 Tasks to do their work, and then it should release them, and after that it should let my other 2 Tasks to do their job.

**The Problem**

i tested this out but unfortunately sometimes i get different/wrong results.

here are 2 output results.

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Just a friendly hint. SemaphoreSlim has a async version so your `mSemaphore.Wait();` could be replaced with `await mSemaphore.WaitAsync();` because your method is already async thanks to the delay you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calls to `mSemaphore.Wait()` and `mSemaphore.Release()` are *inside* your `for` loop. After every iteration of the loop, each task releases the semaphore, then attempts to acquire it again.

Given this, there's nothing to stop task 0, 1, or 2 from releasing the semaphore at the end of a loop, and task3 from acquiring it. The task that released it will go back to the start of its loop, and sit on `mSemaphore.Wait()` again, waiting for another task to release the semaphore.

All of your tasks are running at the same time (apart from a very small initial delay, potentially), and they all have equal priority (SemaphoreSlim doesn't guarantee the order in which things waiting for the semaphore acquire it -- it's essentially random which waiting task will be given it). Therefore it's no surprise that sometimes tasks 0, 1 and 2 get to complete before task3 is given the semaphore, and sometimes things happen in a different order.

If you add some extra logging at the point that each task attempts to acquire the semaphore, actually acquires it, then releases it, that should make it a bit clearer -- you'll be able to see one task release it, and then another task immediately pick it up).

Answer (score 2):

Method [`SemaphoreSlim.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.wait):

> Blocks the current thread until it can enter the `SemaphoreSlim`.

Method [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync):

> Asynchronously waits to enter the `SemaphoreSlim`.

Since your code is asynchronous, you should use `WaitAsync`, not `Wait`. By blocking threads while running asynchronous code, you'll get all kinds of funny effects instead of the behavior you expect. Consider for example that after `await Task.Delay(1000)` your asynchronous workflow may continue running on a different thread, or may not, depending on conditions that you don't control.

Long story short, just replace `mSemaphore.Wait()` with `await mSemaphore.WaitAsync()` and you'll be OK.